# How to use a Loss function in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

As I was reading through the Flux docs, I see there are a [bunch of different loss functions](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/losses/) defined for us that we can use. I understand that the loss tells us how far we are away from from target value. But where do I actually make use of the loss function in the training loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the built in `train!()` function, you can define your loss function and use it during training as follows:

```
loss(x, y) = Flux.Losses.mse(m(x), y)
ps = Flux.params(m)

Flux.train!(loss, ps, data, opt)
```

where `Flux.Losses.mse` is using the built in Mean Squared Error function to calculate the distance between `m(x)` and `y`. You can read more about loss functions in Flux here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/training/#Loss-Functions